# how to implement fp-growth after a k-means clustering in rapidminer

Tags: data-mining, k-means, rapidminer

I'm using rapidminer, and I want to use the output of the k-means operator (attributes of 2 clusters each one of them apart ) as an input for fp-growth to discover relations between variables in each of these clusters.
is there any specific operator to proceed that?

Comment: I don't see how you could meaningfully combine k-means and FP-growth.

Comment: first, i cluster my dataset then for each cluster I retrieve attributes and see the frequent items in one cluster. you don't think that my idea is logical. I'm new to data mining area I need some guides. Thnk you

Comment: That won't give you transactions like needed for FP-growth.